# What does ‘along’ mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image: A view along the coast of Dorset in the United Kingdom]

A view **along** the coast of Dorset in the United Kingdom.

There are several definitions for this word. I’m not sure which one is correct.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary? The noun "view" and the preposition "Along"

Comment: Yes, there are too much meaning! I am not sure which one is correct for this!

Comment: Show us what you have found! You have the context of the image, and the dictionary to give definitions. Give us your best guess. [edit] the question with the dictionary definitions that you think are best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your picture which is *down the coastline* of Dorset

[Along](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/along)

> 1) in a line matching the length or direction of